# How to access first page header texts and replace it using python docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx, paragraph

I have to replace the text on header. I have tried this but it is not working.

```
from docx import Document
document = Document(path_and_filename)
section = document.sections[0]
header = section.header
for paragraph in header.paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from docx import Document

document = Document('foo.docx')
header = document.sections[0].header
paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]
paragraph.text = 'Bar'  # change first page header
document.save('bar.docx')  # see the result after saving to a new file
```

The example above is the most basic way to change the text in a header. There are, of course, more nuances related to headers. For more details, please refer to the [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/hdrftr.html?highlight=header)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a different first-page header (read `different_first_page_header_footer` prop is `True` for the given section), then you'd probably want to use the `first_page_header` property.

```py
section = document.sections[0]
header = section.first_page_header if section.different_first_page_header_footer else section.header
```